# How to create the same GUI as Avast Version7 has deployed for LEFT MENU PANE(Summary,Scan Computer, Real Time Shield)) in WPF using XAML?

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I have to create the same GUI(for Desktop Application) which has used in Avast -Version 7 for the "Left Menu Pane(Summary,Scan Computer, Real Time Shield) etc".
I tried it a lot Already and at last I am asking the name of control that has customized in a way where each tabs on very Left Pane has sub tab like "Summary tab" that listed down following Sub tabs On click 
1)current Service
2)Cloud Service
3)Statistics and other Tab sub-option collapse automatically?
 Will you please give me guideline in brief to achieve Such effect through WPF?

or If you have some other solution for such GUI than please also suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a left aligned Tabs, larger tabs comprise of following smaller tabs, as in WPF we can customize shape of controls. 
Such GUI also has been deployed for Intel Graphics Control Panel(window 7 64 bit).
This kind of GUI is very advantageous, as it holds lots of information in simplest and easier manner for end user.